# Python - Multiply Dictionary Values where type is not String

Tags: python, dictionary, types, key-value, multiplication

Suppose that I have dictionary as follows

`res = {'a':[10, 20, 3.9, 'NA', 'NA', 2.2]}`

I want to multiply the dictionary values with a scalar only where the type is not string.

I've tried multiplying using the following code

```
res['a'] * 10.2
```

**Expected Output**

```
scalar = 10.2

res = {'a':[102, 204, 39.78, 'NA', 'NA', 22.44]}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `isinstance` to detect which are non-strings, and then use `...if...else...` to apply `* 10.2` to those elements:

```py
res = {'a':[10, 20, 3.9, 'NA', 'NA', 2.2]}

res['a'] = [x * 10.2 if not isinstance(x, str) else x for x in res['a']]
print(res) # {'a': [102.0, 204.0, 39.779999999999994, 'NA', 'NA', 22.44]}
```

If you want to "positively" check whether an element is a number, then you can use `if isinstance(x, (float, int))` instead.